# How to create Docker arguments during the building process of a Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is it possible to create a Dockerfile `ARG` while building the docker image?

I am creating a Docker image from previously created images, and would like to label the image I'm creating with the versions of the software used to create the images it's dependent on.

Example: Image A is dependent on image B, which is dependent on image C. Image A can be labeled with:

```
LABEL IMAGE_B_VERSION=${IMAGE_B_VERSION}
LABEL IMAGE_C_VERSION=${IMAGE_C_VERSION}
```

What I have already tried:

```
ARG SOME_ARG=$(some_package --version)
LABEL SOME_ARG=${SOME_ARG}
```

And several variations of this. This does not work, but I believe it gets across what I'm trying to do here.

The internet has not been much help, and I'm thinking this isn't a possible workflow, but decided to ask stackoverflow anyway.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You set the value of `ARG` when you run `docker build`, e.g. `docker build --build-arg SOME_ARG=1.2.3`.

However, since your goal is labeling, you don't even need build args. Instead, just set the labels on the image using the appropriate `docker build` option:

```
$ docker build --label IMAGE_A_VERSION=1.2.3 -t yourimage .
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I was asking for a way to pull variables from the image while it is in the process of being built. I don't think it's possible, though.

Comment: You can inspect an image and get its labels, and then pass that to --label. Or, if this is multistage build, you can build each step separately, do inline LABEL, and inspect for labels.

Comment: The problem is the source images are not created with helpful labels. What I'm currently doing is having to do is `IMAGE_A_VERSION=$(docker run -it --entrypoint bash some_image -c "cd git/path && echo $( git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1)")` in order to get the git SHA of the repo. It works pretty well, but I was kinda hoping that would have been possible as a shell command from within the Dockerfile.